# unshift element in front of a list of children

Tags: jquery

I have a function that keeps a list of children of a div in order to keep them in the original order as they get shifted around

the object with the children is built like this:

```
$('#container').data( 'list', $('#container').children() );
```

When I'm appending a child to this list I can use `push`:

```
$('#container').data( 'list' ).push( element );
```

but when I'm trying to push an element in front of this list like this:

```
$('#container').data( 'list' ).unshift( element );
```

I would expect the `element` to be pushed in front of the `data('list')`, but I get an error:

> $(...).data(...).unshift is not a function

How can I push an element at the beginning of this list of children? I do understand the list of children is not an Array, but since `push` gave no problems, and in another function even `splice` and `slice` worked fine I assumed I could approach this as an array.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eycrg25z/1/) that shows the problem.

Comment: FYI https://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand why the exception is thrown, and why "*...unshift is not a function*", first lets examine what `$('#container').data('list')` is. This value comes from the assignment in `$('#container').data('list',$('#container').children());` and that means it's a jQuery object. As such it is known to have properties that are "array like", but what is it really? let's see:

```js
var cnsl = $('#console');
function log(s) {
  cnsl.append('<span>'+s+'<span><br/>');
}

var children = $('#container').children();

var res = (children.length !== undefined) ? 'has' : 'doesn\'t have'
log('A jQuery object ' + res + ' a length');
res = (children[1] !== undefined) ? 'can' : 'can\'t';
log('A jQuery object ' + res + ' be addressed by index using square brackets');
res = (children.push !== undefined) ? 'has' : 'doesn\'t have'
log('A jQuery object ' + res + ' a push property');
res = (typeof children.push === 'function') ? 'is' : 'isn\'t'
log('A jQuery object\'s "push" property ' + res + ' a function');
res = (children.push === Array.prototype.push) ? 'is' : 'isn\'t'
log('A jQuery object\'s "push" property ' + res + ' the same function as Array.prototype.push');

res = (children instanceof Array) ? 'is' : '<b>isn\'t</b>'
log('A jQuery object ' + res + ' an instance of Array');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

So although it looks like an Array, behaves like an Array, it ***isn't*** an Array.

**So how come `$('x').push === Array.prototype.push`?**
Not sure what the design decision behind this was, but I can speculate this was an optimization based decision as it makes sense that a lot of operations internally require pushing new values into the "array like" jQuery object. It's possible that using something like `this.push(..)` showed performance improvement. `slice()` by the way *is* [documented](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

As `jQuery().push()` isn't a documented function, it should be used for future proof code as that might change in future versions.

---

**How would you go about solving the problem?**
Simple! Use a real array!

```
$('#container').data( 'list', $('#container').children().get() );

//...
$('#container').data( 'list' ).push( element.get(0) );
$('#container').data( 'list' ).unshift( element.get(0) );
```

([fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eycrg25z/2/))

---

#### Tl;DR

A jQuery Object **is not** an Array. There's no reason for `jQuery().unshift()` to exist.